# Acquiring all products with a particular license ID

Tags: c#, performance, api

I am working on refactoring this method on the API.  It's very slow, and can take the browser 12+ seconds to receive the result from the API. Can someone give me something to get me started or point me in the right direction?

```
public List<LicenseProduct> GetProducts(int licenseId)
    {

        var totalpercentage = 0.0;
        var licensedpercentage = 0.0;
        var actualContribution = 0.0;
        var license = _licenseRepository.GetLite(licenseId);
        bool isExecuted = license.LicenseStatusId == 5 || license.LicenseStatusId == 7;
        var claimExceptionCount = 0;
        var products = _licenseProductRepository.GetLicenseProducts(licenseId);
        foreach (var licenseProduct in products)
        {
            licenseProduct.ProductHeader =
                _recsProvider.RetrieveProductHeader(licenseProduct.ProductId);
            licenseProduct.RelatedLicensesNo =
                _licenseProductRepository.GetLicensesNo(licenseProduct.ProductId);
            licenseProduct.LicensePRecordingsNo =
                _licenseProductRecordingRepository.GetLicenseProductRecordingsNo(licenseProduct.LicenseProductId);

            totalpercentage = 0.0;
            licensedpercentage = 0.0;
            actualContribution = 0.0;
            var total=0.0;
            var licensed = 0.0;
            licenseProduct.Message = new List<string>();

            List<LicenseProductConfigurationTotals> licenseProductConfigIdTotals;
            licenseProduct.Recordings = this.GetLicenseProductRecordingsForLicenseDetails(licenseProduct.LicenseProductId, out licenseProductConfigIdTotals);
            foreach (var rec in licenseProduct.Recordings)
            {
                if (rec.Track.ClaimException)
                {
                    licenseProduct.LicenseClaimException = "CLAIM EXCEPTION";
                    claimExceptionCount++;
                }
                totalpercentage = totalpercentage + rec.UmpgPercentageRollup;
                total = total + rec.UmpgPercentageRollup;
                licensed = licensed + rec.LicensedRollup;
            }
            licenseProduct.TotalLicenseConfigAmount = (licensed*100)/total;
            for (int i = 0; i < licenseProduct.ProductHeader.Configurations.Count; i++)
            {
                var licenseProductConfiguration =
                    _licenseProductConfigurationRepository.GetLicenseProductConfiguration(
                        (int)licenseProduct.LicenseProductId,
                        (int)licenseProduct.ProductHeader.Configurations[i].configuration_id);
                if (licenseProductConfiguration != null)
                {

                    licenseProductConfiguration.TotalAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(totalpercentage / licenseProductConfigIdTotals.Count);
                    //licenseProductConfiguration.LicensedAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(licensedpercentage);
                    //licenseProductConfiguration.NotLicensedAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(totalpercentage - licensedpercentage);
                    foreach (var licenseProductConfigIdTotal in licenseProductConfigIdTotals)
                    {
                        if (licenseProductConfigIdTotal.configuration_id == licenseProductConfiguration.configuration_id)
                        {
                            licenseProductConfiguration.LicensedAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(licenseProductConfigIdTotal.LicensedAmount / licenseProductConfigIdTotals.Count);
                            licenseProductConfiguration.NotLicensedAmount = Convert.ToDecimal((totalpercentage - licenseProductConfigIdTotal.LicensedAmount) / licenseProductConfigIdTotals.Count);
                        }
                    }

                    licenseProduct.ProductHeader.Configurations[i].LicenseProductConfiguration =
                        licenseProductConfiguration;
                }
            }

        }
        if (claimExceptionCount>0)
        {
            foreach (var licenseProduct in products)
            {
                licenseProduct.LicenseClaimException = "CLAIM EXCEPTION";
            }
        }
        return products;
    }
```

Comment: Assuming that you're fetching from a database, it looks like this method will make a large number of database queries. Is there a way you could get all of the data using just one query, or a small number?

Comment: `2 + products.Count * 4 + products.Sum(p => p.ProductHeader.Configurations.Count)` round trips!

Answer (score 1):

You have a tons of trips to the database, as much as N^2. To illustrate :

```
public List<LicenseProduct> GetProducts(int licenseId)
{
    // 2
    var license = _licenseRepository.GetLite(licenseId);
    var products = _licenseProductRepository.GetLicenseProducts(licenseId);

    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        // products * 4
        product.ProductHeader = _recsProvider.RetrieveProductHeader(product.ProductId);
        product.RelatedLicensesNo = _licenseProductRepository.GetLicensesNo(product.ProductId);
        product.LicensePRecordingsNo = _licenseProductRecordingRepository.GetLicenseProductRecordingsNo(product.LicenseProductId);
        product.Recordings = this.GetLicenseProductRecordingsForLicenseDetails(product.LicenseProductId, out licenseProductConfigIdTotals);

        for (int i = 0; i < product.ProductHeader.Configurations.Count; i++)
        {
            // products * configurations
            var licenseProductConfiguration = _licenseProductConfigurationRepository.GetLicenseProductConfiguration(
                    (int)product.LicenseProductId,
                    (int)product.ProductHeader.Configurations[i].configuration_id);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem actually stems the design. There isn't much that can be done from the code you posted. I would suggest you to update your question with the rest of repository methods, models or database schema.

---

Now I feel like I shoot myself in the foot, as I just criticized Michael Colon for "not providing any meaningful improvement like an example or a full/partial refactored code, other than stating the obvious", and I just did it.

So here is some nitpicks :

1. There is no benefit in declaring your variables on the top of the method, when you don't use it immediately. Even if they are used in the loop, it still wouldn't make a difference to declare them outside of the loop. They will both be compiled into the same IL. However, having to backtrack while trying to read the lines is frustrating. So, just drop a `var` as needed, or the actually type name if the right-hand side doesn't suggest the type.
2. In the following code :

   ```
   var claimExceptionCount = 0;

   foreach (var product in products)
   {
       foreach (var rec in product.Recordings)
       {
           if (rec.Track.ClaimException)
           {
               product.LicenseClaimException = "CLAIM EXCEPTION";
               claimExceptionCount++;
           }
       }
   }

   if (claimExceptionCount > 0)
   {
       foreach (var licenseProduct in products)
       {
           licenseProduct.LicenseClaimException = "CLAIM EXCEPTION";
       }
   }
   ```

   `ClaimException` are being set twice sometimes, and `claimExceptionCount` could be replaced by a boolean flag :

   ```
   var hasClaimException = false;

   foreach (var product in products)
   {
       foreach (var rec in product.Recordings)
       {
           if (hasClaimException || rec.Track.ClaimException)
               hasClaimException = true;
       }
   }

   if (claimExceptionCount)
   {
       foreach (var licenseProduct in products)
       {
           licenseProduct.LicenseClaimException = "CLAIM EXCEPTION";
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are to many lines of code in one function. Start by moving the code inside the for loops to separate functions.

After the original function is broken into smaller functions then start to tweak the for loops for speed.

Try to make all functions less then 5 lines of code. And instantiate variables only once if possible.

Comment: Firstly, decoupling a long method does help to increase readability. However, it doesn't directly benefit the performance. Secondly, less than 5 lines is a bit too much, it is also ["a hint that you are perhaps breaking the code up too much (which makes it harder to read / understand if you need to navigate between functions)"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133404/what-is-the-ideal-length-of-a-method-for-you). And finally, you didn't suggest any changes, but only some generic instructions.

Comment: It's clearly a badly written function. Readability is the first step in refactoring. I would never pass anything like this in a code review. My change suggestion is rewrite this mega function as a set of smaller functions.

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you, it is poorly written or maintained. That is why it is here. While "divide and conquer" is a good approach/starting point, you didn't provide any meaningful improvement like an example or a full/partial refactored code, other than stating the obvious.

Comment: It is a meaningful suggestion. Try not to pick fights with people. If you don't like what i wrote ignore it. Its not your post. You don't decide what is meaningful or not meaningful. Besides your use of the word decoupling is wrong.